# Rails - Build adapter for several APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I need help on my thoughts on building an adapter for several APIs in Rails.
Let me explain first:

I want my clients to be able to add third-party extensions to my app.
I have a model `Extension` and another `CustomExtension`.

I create the extensions myself, that appear then to the "Available extensions" section. When a user clicks on "Add extension", it goes to the "My extensions" section (which is represented by `CustomExtension`).

I created an extension called `API Connector` and i want it to work as follows:
When a user clicks on "Add extension", he picks a category (that i have defined myself) the API is part of (like "Customer Reviews"). Then, the user will enter some fields like an `api_key` or an `api_endpoint`. Then, i want to be able to connect to this api and display some other fields relevant to the api (like the name of where it comes from, example: for Customer Reviews, if a user connects the Google API for it, i want to rename the extension from API Connector to Google Customer Reviews).

In a few words, I want to be able to connect several and different APIs with the same interface and let the user do it without implementing the API in my project.

EDIT — More info:

The APIs might not have the same authentication process or the same properties. They can be very different from each other.

The technical requirements are RESTful APIs and JSON-based.

Comment: Do each of the APIs have the same properties? For example, do they all authenticate in the same way (`api_key`)? Are they all RESTful? Are they all JSON or XML-based?

Comment: Could you provide more information, and reword your post with a specific question?

Comment: @bodacious I provided more info and answered your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to create a way for users to connect to APIs that are unknown until runtime, based on the parameters that a user defines? If so, there's a Ruby library (now removed from Rails) that's built for allowing easy connection to REST APIs, maybe that could be of help here?

https://github.com/rails/activeresource

So, suppose I want to pull breed info from the Cat API. Here's some example code that would let me define that at runtime:

```rb
require "active_resource"
require "ostruct"

##
# This is just a data-store. It could be an ActiveRecord object or some other set 
# of values that you need for the API. You'll have to establish your own criteria
# for types of API configuration you can support
@config = OpenStruct.new(
  # We need to set a custom header and value
  header_name: 'x-api-key',
  # get your own key here: https://docs.thecatapi.com
  header_value: '96120fe6-0846-41c6-9a1d-8a70e691dd47',
  base_url: "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/",
  # What's the path where this resource can be found
  resource_name: "breeds",
  # don't add ".json" to the URLs
  use_json_extension: false,
)

##
# Create an anonymous class at runtime that inherits from ActiveResource::Base
@custom_extension = Class.new(ActiveResource::Base)

##
# Config our class based on the user-provided values.
@custom_extension.class_eval do
  self.include_format_in_path = @config.use_json_extension
  self.site = @config.base_url
  self.headers[@config.header_name] = @config.header_value
  self.element_name = @config.resource_name
  # Log errors here
  self.logger = Logger.new("./output.log")
end

puts @custom_extension.all.to_s
```

With any luck, that should download a list of cat breeds for you. Which should be enough to demonstrate the concept. The docs for ActiveResource can be found here: https://rubydoc.info/gems/activeresource

*Be careful that you're not importing dangerous content from a source provided by a user!*

Hopefully that's what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks it is the kind of aproach i was looking for. I will look into it and i hope it will fit all of my requirements. Indeed, i was thinking about the dangerous content a user could bring into my app. I will try to prevent it

Comment: Good luck with it :)

Comment: Do you think this would be achievable by using gems like RestClient or HTTParty?

Comment: Yes, either should work. The real challenge here is defining your own API layer between your application and the unknown third-party APIs. Since there are many different ways of authenticating and structuring queries for APIs, your job will be to decide which common patterns you want to support. The library you use is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think i will go with restclient or httparty. I would support authentication by api key but also oauth (as many apis use this authentication mode)